# Using multiple GPUs in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gpu

I am using Matlab and I want to utilize my 2 GPUs
I have a big matrix that does not fit into 1 GPU but half of the matrix fits into 1 GPU. So I want to chop the matrix into half and let each one of my 2 GPUs work on half of the matrix. What I did is the following

```
try 
    parpool('local',gpuDeviceCount)
end
spmd
    gpuDevice
end
dp = 0.00001;
R = zeros(1,2);
parfor k=1:1:2
   if k==1
      M = gpuArray([dp:2*dp:10])
   else
      M = gpuArray([2*dp:2*dp:10])
   end
   R(k) = arrayfun(@(x) myfun,M);
end
```

My question is: how can I know that I indeed create 2 `M` vector (they are different) on each of my GPU? Is there a single built-in function to show this? Why we need the `spmd gpuDevice end`? Currently, I can feel that in terms of speed, the `parfor` seems to be 2 times faster than a regular `for`. But how can I confirm that indeed each GPU stores a different `M`? **I don't know if it actually copied `gpuArray([dp:2*dp:10])` twice and `gpuArray([2*dp:2*dp:10])` twice?**

And after this block of code is finished, I find that my vector `M` does not appear in the workspace. But other variables defined outside the `parfor` code are still in the workspace. If I just use `for` instead of `parfor` (but with a smaller size `M` so that it can fit into 1 GPU), after the `for loop`, the vector `M` is in the workspace and its type is `gpuArray`. Why if I use `parfor`, then after the `parfor loop`, those variables defined within the `parfor loop` are gone?

Answer (score 0):

To answer some of your questions.

1. M is not present after the end of the for loop, because it is a [local variable](https://mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/troubleshoot-variables-in-parfor-loops.html), they are present only on the worker. To make sure your code works as intended, I would suggest to close the parallel computing pool (leaving the parfor in your code) and then use the debugger to set a breakpoint and check M. This way you can check if your code does everything right and then enable the parallel pool. In case you need M for later computations, you have to make it sliced variable of it. Considering the constraints (see same link above), you can either use a 2d matrix or cell array which you initialize outside the parfor.
2. About the use of `gpuDevice`, according to the documentation it is not required but "To identify which GPU each worker is using, call gpuDevice inside an spmd block. The spmd block runs gpuDevice on every worker." Looks like you con't have to include it. [source](http://mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/parallel.gpu.gpudevice.html)